# Confidence intervals in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a scatterplot in ggplot. To the black circle indicating average, I want to add a black horizontal line with a confidence interval for one condition and a black vertical line for a confidence interval for a second condition.

```
#SCATTERPLOT
# Create the scatterplot
scatter_plot <- ggplot(table_all, aes(x = post, y = pre,)) + 
  geom_point(color = "black", size = 12.5) +
  geom_point(size = 12, color = "#C0C0C0") +  
  labs(x = "Post", 
       y = "Pre") +  
  theme_classic(base_size = 35) +
  lims(x = c(0, 3), y = c(0, 3)) +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "#000000") +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(post_mean = mean(table_all$post), pre_mean = mean(table_all$pre)), 
             aes(x = post_mean, y = pre_mean), color = "#000000",  color = "#000000", fill = "black", size = 8, shape = 21, color = "black")  

# Print the scatterplot
print(scatter_plot)
```

Comment: I saw your edit comment. You might consider deleting your question as your data is available via the edit history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option to achieve your desired result using a data.frame of summary stats for which I use `ggplot2::mean_sdl`, two `geom_linerange` and a `geom_segment`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

table_summary <- table_all |>
  summarise(across(c(pre, post), mean_sdl)) |>
  tidyr::unnest_wider(c(pre, post), names_sep = ".")

ggplot(table_all) +
  geom_point(aes(x = post, y = pre),
    size = 4, color = "#C0C0C0"
  ) +
  geom_abline(
    intercept = 0,
    linetype = "dashed",
    color = "#000000"
  ) +
  geom_point(
    data = table_summary,
    aes(x = post.y, y = pre.y),
    color = "black",
    fill = "black",
    size = 4,
    shape = 21
  ) +
  geom_linerange(
    data = table_summary,
    aes(y = pre.y, xmin = post.ymin, xmax = post.ymax),
    color = "black"
  ) +
  geom_linerange(
    data = table_summary,
    aes(x = post.y, ymin = pre.ymin, ymax = pre.ymax),
    color = "black"
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = table_summary,
    aes(
      x = post.ymin, xend = post.ymax,
      y = pre.ymin, yend = pre.ymax,
    ),
    color = "black"
  ) +
  lims(x = c(0, 3), y = c(0, 3)) +
  labs(
    x = "Post", y = "Pre"
  ) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 12)
```